# My rig does not move my character correctly

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, pose-mode

[image][image]I created a character, I inserted the bones and the rig, when I use the pose mode and move the rig my character deforms and I cannot animate it. I searched a lot online but found nothing about it. I hope someone can help me because I don't know what's wrong.[image]

Comment: Hello, hard to tell, please share your file here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Hello, I just uploaded my file, i need help please. Thanks

Comment: Yes but you need to copy paste the link it gives you  ;)

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=8K9bbVyW" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/8K9bbVyW/)

Comment: Sorry, i don't know if it's right, it's the first time for me ...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the normals of your mesh are flipped so it gives bad parening:

[image]

To fix it, select your mesh, select all in *Edit* mode and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> > *Recalculate Outside*. Then reparent to the armature *With Automatic Weight*. It should work much better. If you need to make some corrections, display the good layer, i.e. the one with the bones that are supposed to deform your mesh:

[image]

Then select the armature, shift select the mesh, switch to *Weight Paint* mode, check each bone and give some corrections:

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115924/discussion-on-answer-by-moonboots-my-rig-does-not-move-my-character-correctly).